# Check if all divs are hidden after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have divs with a link in each. After clicking on the link, the div is hidden. I want to make a redirection to another page when all the divs are hidden.

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="checkhide">
    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="btn" onClick="$(this).parent().parent().parent().hide()" role="button">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please post your javascript too?

Comment: $(function()
{
 if ( $("div.checkhide:visible").length === 0)
    alert('all are hidden');
    
});

Comment: $("checkhide:visible").length ===0 at the beginig so the alert is shown whereas all the divs are visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear what you mean 'all' div, it seems this `onClick="$(this).parent().parent().parent().hide()"` only works for ONE div.
Maybe if add class 'hidden' to `<div>` when click `<a >` , and if you know how many div there are, like 4.
Then check whether 'all' div class contain 'hidden', by:

```
$("a").on('click', function(){
// here should be some div you want to hide
  $(".checkhide").addClass("hidden");
})

var hidden_div_number = $("div").find("[class*='hidden']").length; 
if (hidden_div_number==4){
 // do something;
}
```

Comment: Actually there is the link <a href="#" class="btn" onClick="$(this).parent().parent().parent().hide()" role="button">
       in each div. So I want to redirect the user o, another page when he cliks on the last link (that hide the last div that remains)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. That was just a typo. I forgot the "." in my javascript:

```js
 
$(function() { if ( $(".checkhide:visible").length === 0) alert('all are hidden'); });
```

Thank you all!